# Convert (void **) to object in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, queue

I am trying to convert a (void**) object into a queue in C++.

In one file HashTableVoid.cc I use the method find to:

```
bool HashTableVoid::find( const char * key, void ** data)
{
  // Add implementation here
  int i = hash(key);
  HashTableVoidEntry * node = _buckets[i];

while(node){
  if(strcmp(node->_key,key) == 0)
  {
    *data = node->_data;
    return true;
  }
  node = node->_next;
}
return false;
}
```

And in IRCServer.cc I used

```
void IRCServer::sendMessage(int fd, const char * user, const char * password, const char * args)
{
//Get user's room

//Write to room messages
char * temp;
temp = strdup(args);
void ** q;
queue<char*> data;
const char * room = //Found Room;
communication.find(room, q);
data =  (queue<char*>) ((char *)q);
data.push(temp);
//Make sure only 100 elements or less in the list
while(data.size() > 100)
    data.pop();
}
```

I am creating `void ** q` to pass as a parameter to communication. The variable communication is a HashTable where the key is the room name and the value is a unique queue of messages. I am having trouble converting the void object to a queue. I can't change the `find` method.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: exactly what trouble are you experiencing? "trouble" could mean many things.

Comment: when you post code try to indent your code, a tip is to avoid tabs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems that I can see directly:

First you call `find` without initializing `q`, so it doesn't actually point anywhere. So in the `find` function when you dereference do `*data` you dereference an unknown pointer leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I think what you're supposed to do is to declare `q` to be a *single* pointer, and then pass the address of that to the `find` function (emulating *pass by reference*). Like

```
void *q;
...
communication.find(room, &q);
```

However, since you're programming in C++ I don't see a reasong to use double-pointer to emulate pass by reference, since C++ have it built-in:

```
bool HashTableVoid::find( const char * key, void *& data);
```

The above declares the argument `data` as a reference to a pointer.

---

The second problem is your assignment from the pointer `q` to the variable `data`:

```
data =  (queue<char*>) ((char *)q);
```

What you have now (without the changes above), `q` is a pointer to a pointer, and you try to use it as a single pointer, which you then try to cast to a value. A pointer is not a value, and can never be.

Maybe you mean

```
data = *reinterpret_cast<std::queue<char*>*>(q);  // After change detailed above
```

Comment: why use q at all, he could just cast `data` when passing it to find

Comment: You are missing a '>' and a '(' in the reinterpret_cast. Would it look like this: data = *(reinterpret_cast<std::queue<char*>* >)(q); ?

Comment: @CyberSpock what do you recommend?